# Method that pass parameter to retrieve data from mysql java

Tags: java, mysql, methods

I want to create a method when i passed a value to the parameter, it will be passed to the sql statement.
here is what i've tried:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class cobadatabase{
    protected String sn,fn,ln;
    private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement st; 
    public cobadatabase(String studentnumber)
    { 

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studentrecords","root","");
            st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM student WHERE Student_Number=?");
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();


            while (rs.next()){

                sn = rs.getString(1);
                fn = rs.getString(2);
                ln = rs.getString(3);
                SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
                ft.format(rs.getTime("Total Time").getTime());

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

i don't know what is wrong with my code. I just want to retrieve the data for printing

Answer (score 0):

You haven't **set parameter** in `prepareStatement`

```
st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM student WHERE Student_Number=?");
// You need to set the parameter for `?`
st.setString(1, studentnumber);  // Add this code in between..
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

And actually that is not a method.. that is a `Constructor` you are using.. And you are using it for wrong purpose..

Technically, the sole purpose of a Constructor is to initialize the attributes of the object being created, or initialize the environment for use..

For using `database query`, or doing any other kind of task, you should use a method, and invoke that..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like that:

```
public String Func (String par1, String par2) throws SQLException {
     String query;
     query ="SELECT ... WHERE COLUMN_NAME between  +"'"+par1+"'"+" AND " +"'"+par2+"'"+..."; 

    rs = st.executeQuery(query);   // get data or just Execute without getting results
```

Pay attention that Between a String there should be a `" '' "` (non-doubled quotes), whereas numeric values shouldn't.

Comment: @user1249569.. Why have you taken two arguments as OP didn't say anything about that.. He just wants to fetch data for a given `studentnumber`